# Vertically aligning text for game grid not working in flex-box

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

My goal is to make a tic-tac-toe game, but I'm having a lot of difficulty aligning the x and o marks vertically and horizontally.

Here is my Code, where the "marked" values are the ones with letters:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 456px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

li {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

figure {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.marked {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
<figure class="ttt">
  <ul>
    <li class="marked">o</li>
    <li class="marked">x</li>
    <li class="marked">o</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</figure>
```

I've tried so many variations of aligning the text (using divs, trying different properties, values, text types, display types), but I can't get it past looking like this:

[image: tic-tac-toe attempt]

As you can see, it's off-center vertically. I think horizontally it is OK, but again, it seems like it may not be pixel perfect. I've been at this for hours, so I'd appreciate any advice!

Comment: next time please merge your code in the same snippet. The whole reason for a snippet is to be run/parsed. That however does not work if you split your code in seperate snippets.

Comment: your elements are vertically centered. However you don't use capital but lower case letters. As such they don't fill the entire line-height. Use capital letters or symbols instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out.

I added `text-transform: uppercase` for the `li` styles and slightly reduced `font-size` for `.marked`.

The problem seems to be that you are aligning UPPERCASE letters, but using lowercase.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 456px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

li {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

figure {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.marked {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
<figure class="ttt">
  <ul>
    <li class="marked">o</li>
    <li class="marked">x</li>
    <li class="marked">o</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `line-height` on the `<li>` elements to align the text vertically, and use `text-align: center;` to align the text horizontally.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 456px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

li {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  /* HERE */
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 125px;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

figure {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.marked {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
<figure class="ttt">
  <ul>
    <li class="marked">o</li>
    <li class="marked">x</li>
    <li class="marked">o</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</figure>
```

PS: If you want this to look good on different screen sizes, you should probably switch out `px` for percentage values. Check out [this article on the topic](https://medium.com/@julienetienne/pixels-are-dead-faa87cd8c8b9) if you're interested.